# Prove $X_nY_n\overset{P}{\to}XY$.

Tags: probability

Let the random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n,Y_1,Y_2,\dots,X$ and $Y$, be defined on a common probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, and suppose $X_n\overset{P}{\to}X$ and $Y_n\overset{P}{\to}Y$. Prove $X_nY_n\overset{P}{\to}XY$.

Obviously this makes intuitive sense, and I suspect the proof is very simple, but for some reason I am stuck trying to work out the details. I want to show that for all $\varepsilon,\delta$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$,
$$
P(|X_nY_n-XY|\geq\varepsilon)\leq\delta.
$$
I know that in some sense
$$
(\{X_n\text{ close to }X\}\land\{Y_n\text{ close to }Y\})\implies\{X_nY_n\text{ close to }XY\}.
$$
I want to use the contrapositive of this which would be that
$$
\{X_nY_n\text{ not close to }XY\}\implies(\{X_n\text{ not close to }X\}\lor\{Y_n\text{ not close to }Y\}).
$$
However I'm not sure how to make this idea concrete and fit it into the complete proof. Is this even the right approach? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think that answer assumes that $X,Y$ are finite because otherwise how can we choose $K$ such that $P(|X|>K)<\frac\delta 2$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449161/convergence-in-probability-product?rq=1