# Is it true that for any random variable $X$, there $\mathbb{P}(X>k)\to0$ as $k\to\infty$?

Tags: probability

Is it true that for any random variable $X$, there $\mathbb{P}(X>k)\to0$ as $k\to\infty$? I have seen this used in some proofs. For example [Convergence in Probability, Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449161/convergence-in-probability-product?rq=1). But I don't see why this is true. Is it not possible to have a random variable that takes on value $\infty$ with a probabilty $p>0$? Then this would mean that $\mathbb{P}(X>k)\geq p$. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you allow the value $\infty$, yes you are right.

Comment: So have they assumed that $X$ is finite in the proof I linked?

Comment: RVs are usually defined as functions $X \rightarrow \mathbb R$, so the assumption would be very common.

Comment: By definition, a random variable is simply a function $X:\Omega \to \mathbf{R}$ that is measurable relative to $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{B}_\mathbf{R}$ (the sigma field of events and the Borel sigma algebra). Then $\mathbf{P}(X > k) \to 0$ _is_ a theorem, alas, an easy one. The events $\{X > k\}$ are decreasing (if $X > k+1$ then $X > k$ too!) so the probability of this sequence is the probability of the limit of the sequence, i.e. $\mathbf{P}(X > k) \to \mathbf{P}(X > k, \forall \ k \in \mathbf{N}) = \mathbf{P}(X \in \varnothing) = \mathbf{P}(\varnothing) = 0.$

Comment: since it involves differences going to zero, convergence in probability maybe doesn't make sense if your functions are $\infty$ valued on sets of positive measure.

Comment: Convergence in measure (or probability) also requires finite valued measurable functions a.e. because otherwise the difference could not even be defined (remember $+\infty + (-\infty)$ is not defined)

Comment: By the way, in the literature, a random variable takes the value $\infty$ with probability zero, if you go higher up, they will take about "extended random variables."

Comment: You can invent an example where you start with $\$1$, and so long as you have more than zero at the following steps you add $\$1$ with probability $p=\frac23$ and subtract $\$1$ with probability $1-p=\frac13$, where $X$ is the number of steps until you reach zero.  Then, since $p>\frac12$, you can show $P(X \le k) \to \frac1p-1 \not=1$ as $k$ increases as there is a positive probability $2-\frac1p=\frac12$ that you never reach zero, i.e. that $X$ does not have a finite value.

Comment: By definition of a probability distribution you have: $1=lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} F_X(x) = lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} P(X\leq x)$. So, as x goes to infinity, $P(X >x)$ goes to zero. This all by definition.